# Why Expectation for estimates of projection in least squares

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, expected-value, projection

I understand that in the [least square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) setting, the [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) of $\mathbf{y}$ onto the column space of $\mathbf{X}$ is the vector $\mathbf{Xb}$, where the vector $$\mathbf{b=(X'X)^{-1}Xy}$$ Thus the matrix, $\mathbf{P =X(X'X)^{-1}X}$ is the projection matrix which, when it premultiplies $\mathbf{y}$, results in the linear projection that identically mimics the population counterpart $\mathbf{{\mathbb E}[y{\mid}X]}$ when the conditional mean  is also linear.

Now, what William Greene (2018) mentions on p.35 is that the linear projection, "$\mathit{proj}$($\mathit{y}{\mid}\mathbf{x}$) estimates $\mathbf{x'\{{\mathbb E}[xx']\}^{-1}{\mathbb E}[x}\mathit{y}]$", which is also $\mathbf{{\mathbb E}[\mathit{y}{\mid}X]}$ when the conditional mean is linear.

I am a beginner in econometrics, who is unsure why the Expectations are being taken in $\mathbf{x'\{{\mathbb E}[xx']\}^{-1}{\mathbb E}[x}\mathit{y}]$, since there is no trace (not being used in the matrix sense) of Expectations in the matrix $\mathbf{P}$, which I guess is the matrix counterpart of $\mathit{proj}$($\mathit{y}{\mid}\mathbf{x}$).

And if for a valid reason Expectations must be taken in the above case, then why is there no Expectation for $\mathbf{x'}$?

**Note:** Greene's text uses $\mathbf{x}$ to denote the "transpose of the row $\mathbf{x'}$" of matrix $\mathbf{X}$. Please note the difference in this notation compared to standard notation.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the non-invertibility of the singular matrix $\mathbf{xx'}$? (again, note the difference in notation w.r.t $\mathbf{x}$). But the how do you show this for the case where the random vector $\mathbf{x}$ is continuous?

Comment: In econometrics, often $x$ is treated as random, that way the expectation enters